# Are there well-established design patterns on implementing a user prompt?

Tags: c, prompt

I'm working on a embedded project which reads a joystick and moves an actuator within a 3d space accordingly. Now I would like to provide a user prompt available over serial line as an alternative option as user input. User input will be G-Code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code.

I'm not unexperienced with creating C code, however, I never had to deal with text input before. Are there any well established design patterns on how software of this kind is implemented in a easy-to-read/maintanable way?

Comment: The `gets()` function from `stdio.h` gets `stdin`.

Comment: OT: @EliSadoff `gets()` isn't C any more for good reasons, do **not** use it! Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @EliSadoff `gets` is so vile and evil it is no longer part of the standard library, and should be avoided with extreme prejudice.

Comment: There is no simple answer. The user interface is an entire topic in itself, often at least equal to the actual task in hand.

Comment: No magic, *prompt*, *read input*, *validate input*, *handle error condition as required*. It just depends on your requirements. The most general would be *prompt*, then *while (read invalid) repeat..**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "design pattern" for a user prompt.

Design patterns are of marginal value, at best.  They were created in arm-flapping response to the evident catastrophe that most programmers are unable to think for themselves.  Consequently, they are given a lengthy catalogue of previous thoughts, along with finely detailed instructions about how to map their thoughts to these cast-in-stone homologues.

Here's a brilliant example of a "design pattern": it's somehow EVIL to use a global variable.  So, instead, instantiate a Singleton class (which--if you're not careful--will require you to employ the brokered services of a SingletonFactory [but I digress]) and provide "getter" and "setter" methods that access the encapsulated datum.  Result: instead of one line of code that's out there, on the ledge, provide fifteen lines of code that are out there, on the ledge.  HOGWASH!

Many will take offense at this statement.  If they but thought about it, they would realize that they have fallen victim to a sham.  Design patterns are like rubrics in a "Common Core" English essay assignment: assume that the student is utterly unable to generate creative, properly structured English by himself, and so provide ridiculously detailed "guidance" on just what to say and just how to say it.

Think for yourself.  That's the best advice anyone can give you, anywhere, ever.

Comment: ooooh.... the GoF police are gonna get you for that. :)

Comment: To be fair, some of the very same people who would claim -- not without justification -- that using globals is poor form would also claim that using the Singleton pattern is poor form.  Indeed, several of the same reasons apply.  I am all for thinking for yourself, but I'm also for benefiting from experience, both mine and others'.  Design pattern usage is not inherently a reasonable measure of code quality, but design patterns, thoughtfully chosen and applied, *can* help you write quality code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Design patterns, like any other tool in the toolbox (e.g. globals) have their uses. To use one or not, should be decided with care (i.e. not slavishly). I use object pools a lot, because I find them useful. I also create a singleton [of sorts] that combines a bunch of items [that would otherwise be globals]. Any technique being used, should be evaluated in the particular context: Why are we using it? What value does it provide in this particular instance? What issues does it solve [or potentially create]?